# Is there a way to serve different resolution images to different devices?

Tags: theme-development, themes, images

I am making a mobile site, and I want to serve higher resolution images to devices with high pixel density, and normal image to the rest, is there a Wordpress functionality or plugin to help me do that?

I'm not looking for non-wordpress libraries/plugins.

Comment: "libraries"... WP consist out of dozens of external libraries. Themes, Plugins, MU-Plugins, dropins are all just wrappers for external code. Add a comment on top of the main file and guess what: You got a Theme, Plugin, MU-Plugin or Dropin.

Comment: totally. if you have the different sized images available then you will have to tell your theme which ones to use by detecting the browser and selecting the right image. the code for this should be easy to write. look into: add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ) for the images and then dynamically select the image size based on browser detection for your entire theme.

Comment: You can also do this with CSS using Media Queries.

Comment: @Innate the "easy to write code" is my question exactly - is there anything already made for wordpress for this purpose or should I write it myself?

Comment: If you are capable of writing something like this yourself it will be purpose built and lighter than any generic plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some plugins that may be just what you're looking for:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-retina-2x/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-responsive-data-image/

.. also take a look at this post: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adaptive-images

https://github.com/JorgenScott/WP-Resolutions